# Need a SQL Server 2008 case statement to evaluate a table and return two values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm a novice SQL programmer and have been banging my head against this all morning, so please bear with me. My situation is this: I have a table of SKUs that need to be sent to our eCommerce website. Each of these SKUs has a 'quantity', an 'active' value, and a 'discontinued' value. This was easy enough to handle when we were dealing with one SKU at a time, but now I have to send kits, which contain one or more SKUs.

For example, if my Kit's ID is 000920_001449_001718_999999 (a combination of four SKUs) I need to collect data for the entire set of SKUs like so:

[image: Result of query]

Here's the logic I need to incorporate:

1. If any of the SKUs have null or WEBNO as an IsActive value, the entire kit must return WEBNO. Otherwise, return WEBYES.
2. If any of the SKUs have null or '1' as an IsDiscontinued value, the entire kit must return IsDiscontinued = '1'. Otherwise, return a 0.

My code is a bit of a mess, but here's what I've managed so far:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'WEBNO' in
(
    SELECT IsActive
    FROM #SkusToSend as Sending
    RIGHT JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT * FROM [eCommerce].[dbo].[Split] (
          '000920_001449_001718_999999'
          ,'_') 
    ) as SplitSkus
    on Sending.SKU = SplitSkus.items
) THEN 'WEBNO'
ELSE 'WEBYES'
END
```

My question is this: Is it possible to write a statement that parses through my example table, returning only one row of 'IsActive' and 'IsDiscontinued'? I've tried using GROUP BY and HAVING statements on those fields, but always get multiple rows returned.

The code I have handles the WEBNO value, but not NULL, and doesn't even start to take into consideration the IsDiscontinued field yet. Is there a concise way to parse this together, or a better way to handle this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a combination of `ISNULL` and `MIN` / `MAX` should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    MIN(ISNULL(sending.IsActive, 'WEBNO')) AS IsActive,
    MAX(ISNULL(sending.IsDiscontinuted, 1)) AS IsDiscontinuted
FROM 
( 
    SELECT * FROM [eCommerce].[dbo].[Split] (
      '000920_001449_001718_999999'
      ,'_') 
) AS SplitSkus 
LEFT JOIN #SkusToSend AS Sending
    AS Sending.SKU = SplitSkus.items
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. That is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be easier if you had a working example of some sample data in those tables.  From guessing it looks like you have a table function splitting a string apart and giving multiple rows.  You have some temp table that right joins to that so that is taking the function and essentially returning all rows it gets even if there are nulls in the temp table.  This could return multiple rows as if you have a condition where you expect a single entity on a left or right join and there is a null at times you will get multiples.  Or if you have a value repeated you will get multiples.  You would have to ensure that you get one one result I am believing from your

```
Case when 'WEBNO' in 
(
```

As while the logic may be correct to return the 'WEBNO' answer, it may be repeating the row result multiple times as the engine may interpret 'this happened' once, twice, three times.  You could alleviate this by potentially doing a

```
'Select Distinct IsActive'
```

Which will make the expression return only a single result that is distinct for that column return.

Again this would be easier if we could see examples of what data those objects contained but this would be my guess.

Comment: The temporary table only contains a SKU, Quantity, IsActive, and IsDiscontinued field. I'm joining it with a function that splits out the kit into its SKU pieces. When I used the Distinct keyword as suggested, I get NULL, WEBNO, and WEBYES back from the query, which is fine, but my CASE needs to handle WEBNO and NULL, and I still need to figure out the IsDiscontinued piece of the puzzle...